# Is there a way to upload into language folder in codeigniter through file upload

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to provide language support to the admin of my project , so if the admin chooses for language support he can add a file and select a language (this file contains values of that particular language of some strings which we used in the entire project ). So I was thinking to handle a text file upload and write it to language folder in system directory of CodeIgniter. but I am not sure if this is possible as I am getting

"Permission denied" while uploading . Is there a better way to do this functionality? I was thinking to make the language folder in www directory and use it from there.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the permission of the language folder.

Comment: but any call to language folder will be redirected to app folder in codeigniter ?

Comment: Try after removing the .htaccess file from the system folder.

Comment: yes , but i want to write to language folder while the site is live . so i cant remove .htaccess

Comment: Hence proved. You can't directly write to that folder until that .htaccess file exists.

Comment: Change location of language folder to some other place where the application can access and change the codeigniter referral path pointed to language directory,

Comment: yes i was looking for a way to add it to language folder in sys directory , using in www is an option i knew long back .

Comment: @Teja Reddy You shouldnt put ANYTHING in the system directory or modify the files in it at all. There is a language folder in `/application`, you should use that one.